# Swiftmailer broken pipe error

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer, symfony-2.8, rhel6

I am using:

- RHEL 6.6
- Symfony 2.8.18
- PHP 5.5.30
- Apache 2.4.10
- MySQL 5.1.73

I have the two following error messages when I want to send 5 emails or more (it works perfectly if I send 1 or 2 or 4 emails...):

> Notice: fwrite(): send of 40 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe in
>   /appli/projects/APACHE-PHP/apache_2.4/htdocs/APACHE-PHP/project/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php
>   on line 231
>
> Notice: fwrite(): send of 6 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe in
>   /appli/projects/APACHE-PHP/apache_2.4/htdocs/APACHE-PHP/project/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php
>   on line 231

I added a Try/Catch (by searching on other posts):

```
foreach($messages as $message){     
    try{
        $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
    }catch (Exception $e){
        printf("Error: %s\n", $e->getMessage());
        $mailer->getTransport()->stop();
        sleep(10);
    }
}
```

But it is still not working...

This is weird because I can send more than 5 emails (12 emails for example) if I try a simple example using the PHP mail function:

```
<?php
$msg = "Suspendisse vestibulum et lectus eu pellentesque. ";

$headers = "From: mypersonalemail@anyidea.com" . "\r\n" .
"CC: mypersonalemail@anyidea.com";

for($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++){
    mail("recipient@anyidea.com","Test",$msg, $headers);
}
?>
```

It works perfectly with the PHP mail() function but I can send more than 5 emails when I try with Swiftmailer... Why??

Any suggestion(s)?

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous bug reports on this, and several workarounds in the relevant threads.

- SwiftMailer (open): https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/490
- Laravel: (bug report): https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/4573
- Laravel: (Pull Report): https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/13583

(The simple try/catch you posted above [or close enough](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/490#issuecomment-60540720) worked for me, so am reposting it for others that are looking for a solution.)

```
while (true) {
    while ($message = $queue->pop()) {
        try { $mailer->send($message); } 
        catch (Exception $e) { printf("Error: %s\n", $e->getMessage()); }
    }
    $mailer->getTransport()->stop();
    sleep(5);
}
```